# How to find exclude records with 2 values

Tags: sql, ms-access

How to search only "closed , closed" record ?

```
Record# Facility Address     Facility Status  Closed Date    Facility Name

1   1338 LAS JUNTAS WAY      LICENSED                        ABC TECH
2   1338 LAS JUNTAS WAY      CLOSED           03/02/2020     XYZ TECH
3   1158 BONT LANE           CLOSED           05/12/2022     PQR TECH
```

In the above example , SQL query should not return record number 2 based upon status.
Query should fetch record #3 only.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.

```sql
SELECT T2.[ID], T2.[Facility Type], T2.[Facility Status], T2.[Facility City], T2.[Facility Address]
FROM T2
WHERE (T2.[Facility Status] = 'Closed'  AND  T2.[Facility Status] <> 'LICENSED ' ) AND  T2.[Facility City] = 'Walnut Creek';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what "closed, closed" means, but your filter can be reduced to:

```sql
SELECT 
    T2.[ID], 
    T2.[Facility Type], 
    T2.[Facility Status], 
    T2.[Facility City], 
    T2.[Facility Address]
FROM 
    T2
WHERE 
    T2.[Facility Status] = 'Closed' 
    AND 
    T2.[Facility City] = 'Walnut Creek'
    AND
    T2.[ID] Not In 
        (Select T.ID 
        From T2 As T 
        Where 
            T.ID = T2.ID And
            T.[Facility Status] = 'Licensed' And 
            T.[Facility City] = 'Walnut Creek')
```

Comment: Hi Gustav,  it does not work.  record#2     1338 LAS JUNTAS WAY      CLOSED           03/02/2020     XYZ TECH is still returned with your query.   I want only record #3 3   1158 BONT LANE           CLOSED           05/12/2022     PQR TECH  to be returned with the query

Comment: Well, you could have stated that originally ...

Comment: Thanks Gustav for internal table concept .                                                                              since ID is not tied the the facility address so select on  ID did not work .   For the same address there is a different ID.

Comment: OK, then modify to care of that. We only have your posted sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
                                                            SELECT 
T2.[ID], 
T2.[Facility Type], 
T2.[Facility Status], 
T2.[Facility City], 
T2.[Facility Address]
```

FROM T2
WHERE
T2.[Facility Status] = 'Closed'
AND
T2.[Facility City] = 'Walnut Creek'
AND
T2.[Facility Address] Not In
(Select T.[Facility Address]
From T2 As T Where
T.[Facility Address]= T2.[Facility Address] And
T.[Facility Status] = 'Licensed' And
T.[Facility City] = 'Walnut Creek') ;